# objective-c byte array length different between 32 and 64 bit compile

Tags: objective-c, arrays, byte, 32bit-64bit

I have following defined in a .h file:

```
extern Byte cADPU_IDToken[];
```

and in a corresponding .m file:

```
Byte cADPU_IDToken[]   = {0xDF,0x00,0x06,0x07};
```

When executing the app for iPad2 (32 bit) I get for following code:

```
NSData *test = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cADPU_IDToken length:sizeof(&cADPU_IDToken)];
NSLog(@" ..ARM64... %lu", test2.length);
```

Result: 4 bytes (that's correct).

When executing for iPad5 (64 bit) I get as result: 8 bytes !?

What am I doing wrong  and how to solve so the App runs correctly on any 32/64 iPad/iPhone ?

Regards,

S

Comment: `sizeof` does not give the length of the byte array. It gives the size of the pointer. You will get 4 and 8 no matter how many bytes you store in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read [64-Bit Transition Guide for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/Cocoa64BitGuide.pdf).
For your case solution is to change 'Byte' to 'uint8_t':

> Our recommendation is to choose a
>   C99 representation that accurately reflects the range of values your application requires.
>
> uint8_t:  0 to 255

Comment: Changing Byte to uint8_t does not solve the problem. It remains 8 as a result!?